# phpMyAdmin - Establishing a MySQL Connection with a software

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, tableau-api

I would like to establish a **MySQL connection** between a data visualization software (Tableau Software) and a database shared between several computers **through phpMyAdmin** - which by the way uses the port 80.

When configuring this connection, I am asked to fill the fields "Server name", "Username" and "Password".

What is the **exact "Server name" related to phpMyAdmin** ?

Thank you for paying attention.

Comment: `phpMyAdmin` isn't a server. It's just a web application that allows you to view and manage a database. The server name is presumably in the phpMyAdmin configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The server name is the hostname/IP of the MYSQL database server.

**Example 1 (Local)**

You have a application that runs on the same box as the mysql server then the hostname/ip is localhost(127.0.0.1). When you login to PHPMyadmin he will authorize to the hostname "localhost" or IP "127.0.0.1".

**Example 2 (external)**

If you have the mysql server running on another box eg. db.domain.example (IP: 1.1.1.1) then the hostname will be db.domain.example ( or IP: 1.1.1.1).

I hope this helped you, if not please let me know.

Regards,

Comment: In my case, I have to access the database on another IP which uses its own localhost. For the moment, phpMyAdmin enables me with success to access to this localhost. But when I use this IP as the server name from my software as you've just suggested me it still doesn't work ... Regards.

Comment: Did you get any error message back? You need to configure the mysql server to accept external connections. [Good starting point how to do that.](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/remotemysql.htm)

Comment: The error message is "An error occured while communicating with MySQL Database. The connection to the data source might have been lost".
Thank you for the link but my computer is processing with Windows and not Linux.

Comment: Sorry my bad.. the my.cfg file is the same on windows though. That error message is for me uknown. Let me see if I can find something.